# Запрос/Ответ на примере регистрации

Tags: http, post, get

Пообщался с программистом, но не понял, вот сам пример:
Заходим на сайт и видим кнопку регистрации, вписываем все данные в форму (наши данные направляются в базу данных, как я понимаю вот таким принципом: 
клиент -> сервер -> база данных (куда записываются данные из нашей формы). 
Далее если мы хотим авторизоваться, мы сначала вписываем специально некорректные данные, которые отправляются таким принципом:
 клиент -> сервер -> база данных (запрос смотрит какие там данные и далее возвращает ответ таким принципом: 
 база данных -> сервер -> клиент (обратно так сказать). Где на клиенте мы видим допустим текст красным цветом: Вы ввели некорректные данные. А если мы попытались авторизоваться и ввели правильные данные по такому принципу:
 клиент -> сервер -> база данных (проверила какие данные находятся в базе данных и какие мы ввели, если они одинаковые, то мы получаем ответ и успешно авторизовываемся). Попытался более менее правильно вам рассказать, подскажите правильно ли я думаю или нет, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что именно не поняли? Ну вообще мысль создания сайта с авторизацией/регистрацией правильная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно вы расписали, все запросы обрабатываются файлами php, при вводе верного пароля, активируется сессия, которая и дает вам доступ к вашему кабинету.

Все данные хранятся в базе данных, php файлы являются обработчиками запросов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему именно php файлы, только для Питона или С# нельзя сделать что ли или как? Почему именно Php?

Comment: можно конечно, это разные языки) принцип все равно один

Comment: я просто расписал на примере картинки, поэтому и php

Comment: А всё хорошо, спаибо большое